# Bootstrap background image won't scroll

Tags: html, css, background-image, bootstrap-5

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <!--Bootstrap-->
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <!--Font awesome icons-->
 <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4e9b2916e9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <!--Google fonts-->
 <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
 <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Bakery</title>
</head>
<body>
      
  <header>

        <!--Navbar-->

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white p-2 h5">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                  <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="No solo pan y café logo brown">
              </a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              
                         
                <div class="d-flex me-lg-5 mx-auto">
                    <ul>
                        <li><span class="social-icon social-facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span></li>
                        <li><span class="social-icon social-google"><i class="fa fa-google"></i></span></li>
                        <li><span class="social-icon social-tripadvisor"><i class="fa fa-tripadvisor" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
              </nav>
            </header>
            

              
                <!--Main-->

                  <section>
                   </section>
              



          



    

    <!--Js-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

It's my first post here so here goes nothing!
I'm in the process of learning html/css and right now I'm stuck on Bootstrap 5 background image.
I try to set it on the whole body, but the problem is it shows only a part of the image, the rest should be there when I scroll down but I can't scroll anything.

Here's the screenshot of the website, as you can see, a lower part of the background is missing, I should be able to scroll down but it just won't let me. Who would've thought a background image is such a pain in the neck in Bootstrap.

What am I doing wrong? Please be gentle! Thanks!

Website screenshot [Website screenshot](https://ibb.co/pbtf5h0)

```css
body {
    background-color: #eee;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    background-image:url(/images/sofiya-levchenko-c07dv6i8P4Q-unsplash1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: fixed;
       }
```

Comment: did you set a proper height to your element? if you want it fullscreen use: width: 100%; and height: 100%;

Comment: it is `background-attachment` not `background-position`  that you seem to need. https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment

Comment: Even with the background-attachment set to fixed, the same problem remains. The lower part of the background image, therefore the background bottom is not showing and I can't scroll down

Answer (score 0):

You should use `background-attachement`, not `background-position`.

```css
body {
        background-color: #eee;
        font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
        font-weight: 300;
        background-image:url(/images/sofiya-levchenko-c07dv6i8P4Q-unsplash1.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;
     }
```

Source: [Mozilla MDN on background-attachment](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your .row with .container or .container-fluid and it will solve the issue.

And if it won't scroll in mobile view you can make sure to use the meta tag in your head tag